# Programmatically scroll to a view within a scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to programmatically scroll a view within the scrollview. I can do this making:

```
 View viewToShow= ...
 ScrollView scrollView= ...;
 scrollView.scrollTo(0,viewToShow.getTop());
```

But it only works if the layout has been measured. The result of `viewToShow.getTop()` within onCreate() is 0 always, so it does not work.

How can I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override:

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
```

In this function, layout values are calculated (margin included)